# How can I do that without WIN32 API?

Tags: winapi, countdown, keydown

So, here is a countdown.
My aim is the next: if you don't do anything for the given time (ent_sec) the countdown will  reach 0 after a time and return with 0,   BUT if you press down the letter c (code: 99) the countdown stops and you can enter your PIN code and return with it.
I have already solved the problem with Windows.h in the next way:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
```

This solves the problem is through WIN32 API (in this case you have to press SPACE, not letter 'c'), but it revealed that I can't use any WinAPI function (school project). So I rewrite this line to the following:

```
if (getchar() == 99)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work in the proper way, cause my countdown stops in almost every second until I dont't press some "wrong" key (for example I press 'x', then the countdown goes forward, but in the next sec it stops again)... In the first solution (win func) this problem doesn't exist... So how can I fix that? Thanks.  Here is the whole code of my function:

```
unsigned Timer::DownCount
{
  int ent_sec = this.time;

  cout << "The counter has started (" << this.time << "sec), press 'C' to enter your PIN code: " << endl;


  while (ent_sec >= 0)                                       
  {
    if (getchar() == 99)    // c letter's code is 99 in ANSI (or ASCII dunno)                       
    {                                               
        unsigned code;

        cout << "PIN code: ";
        cin >> code;    

        return code;
    }

    else
    {
        SecCounter(1);     // this function counts 1 secundum
        cout << ent_sec << endl;
        ent_sec--;
    }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a standard way to do this that will work across all platforms, but here's one way of doing it that will work on Windows without actually using Windows API functions.

```
int getch_nowait()
{
  if (!kbhit()) return -1;
  return getch();
}
```

Then your check just becomes `if (getch_nowait() == 99) ...`

This code may be compiler specific. If it doesn't work for you, it'll help if you tell us what compiler and operating system you are using.

Comment: Hi. Really thanks for your post. Im using Windows7 and Visual Studio 2012. I look after that kbhit() function, but the problem is that it is in conio.h, which I also can't really include... :( But I'm open-minden for every solution, so if you (or somebody else) have any other idea please don't hesitate and write it. Thx

Comment: I wonder if you would be allowed to use ncurses.h if it could be made to work. I believe that's what you would use to achieve something like this on a Unix system, but there is apparently also a port available for Windows that might work. It's no more standard than using conio.h, but if your school is just against using Windows specific libraries they might allow it.